# get value from instance knowing its struct type

Tags: c++, struct

There is a structure defined and instance is initialized.

```
struct details{
    int numb;
    string name;
    string address;
    };

details det={2,"abc","def"};
```

Now in generic implementation, we know the struct type(`details`) and member name (say `name`). Only one instance is defined for that structure. My question is can we get the value of `name` i.e., `"abc"` without using instance `det`?

Comment: What are you *really* trying to accomplish? [This smells like a Y to a hidden X](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: This sounds like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378). Why do you think, that you need this?

Comment: You could *technically* get it by looking at the local stack frame, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for here...

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense, because it is contradictory: "_can we get the value of name from instance det i.e., "abc" without using instance det?_". It is like "How can I eat an apple without having the apple?"

Comment: @gvs - Nobody was commenting on your English, it's the requirement which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @StoryTeller my requirement is clear. Getting the value from instance by using its struct type and its member name.

Comment: It was clear enough to produce an answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Well, here's to hoping the OP doesn't start debating with you about how well your answer suits them. I still think this is an XY problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller: Every single question ever asked is an XY problem to a certain extent - we solve individual problems then apply the solutions to create a building block, part of a larger puzzle, until our whole project is finished. I don't think rejecting fairly simple questions about the language on the basis of it being "an XY problem" is particularly useful, personally. We're here to answer questions, not consult on the parent project's overarching architecture and design decisions.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - *"To an extent"* yes. And please do not assume the rejection is about the simplicity of the question. I get the distinct feeling that the sensible solution to the OP's real problem will not be the sensible solution to their literal problem. Very much like the linked meta post illustrates. But no matter, we'll see I suppose.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I agree, but it is now up to them to take the information they have learned here today, and use it to move another step along the path towards their final, finished solution. Skipping that step doesn't really help anybody.

Answer (score 3):

No.

The language doesn't know that you only have one instance of `details`, and it certainly doesn't know where to find it if all you tell it is the type. There is no "database" of instances that it can consult.

It sounds like you should put these pieces of data into a namespace, instead:

```
namespace details {
    int numb       = 2;
    string name    = "abc";
    string address = "def";
}

// Refer to details::name practically anywhere
```

Now you have effectively created a "database" of information, and the string called `name` is in it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It"s working.. But cannot change the format of struct into namespace due to some constraints in implementation. By the way, I am also not sure whether it is possible or not.

Comment: @gvs: If you can't use this solution, then you are stuck passing around a pointer or reference to your class instance. The language cannot do what you have described.

Comment: Yes, can implement pointer or reference concept. If there is any solution using pointers concept, please provide with an example.

Comment: @gvs: I'm not going to teach you how to use pointers or references here. You should read the relevant chapter of your C++ book.

Answer (score 0):

You can by storing a global pointer to the instance.
However, there are downsides to using global variables. You should avoid it if possible.

```
struct details{
    int numb;
    string name;
    string address;

    static details* instance;
};

details* details::instance = nullptr;

details det={2,"abc","def"};
details::instance = &det;
```